# How to insert HTML content into Silverlight? Is it possible?

Tags: html, silverlight

I have some html documents like this:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <p style="text-align:Left;font-size:20;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;color:#000000;">
      <span>asfsdf</span>
    </p>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'd like to display them in Silverlight 4. They would be some read-only content. Is it possible?

In our Silverlight application we have some ChildWindow. Also, I have a HTML to XAML converter but I don't want to display it after converting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this, depending on where Silverlight is hosted.

1. Out-of-browser
   You can use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) control.
2. In-browser
   You can float HTML over the top of your Silverlight control to make it appear as though the content is in your control. You have to set `windowless` to `true` for this to work. [This blog](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/09/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of.html) has a nice explanation on how to use this approach.

Comment: The silverlight application is in browser mode. The solution mentioned in this blog would be a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890068/displaying-rtf-or-html-in-silverlight-4/4902791#4902791) I've detailed written about edit and view rich text formats in Silverlight 4.
You can implement your own HtmlViewer control, which will work in windowless mode of silverlight or use one of those third party controls.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I'm trying to write a view myself instead of using the feature in Telerik.